# I can't use the "sudo" command on my server

Tags: sudo

After I edited the `/etc/sudoers.d/my_sudoers` file with `nano` I was unable to use `sudo`.

The following errors are giving when trying to use `sudo`:

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/my_sudoers near line 4
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I know exactly what is wrong but I have no way to edit the file since it is owned by root.

I can't use `chown` to change the ownership because that would involve using `sudo`.

`pkexec` has not been installed or configured on the server so I'm not sure if that is an option.

I have tried using the copy command to make a back up but I get the same errors.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Please don't recommend reboot the server because that is not an option.

Comment: Why wasn't `visudo(8)` used? That has a verification step before writing out the file.

Comment: You might check if any co-workers have a root shell open on that box...but I'm guessing there's no chance of that in your environment.

Comment: @thrig is correct -- this is exactly the reason why `visudo` exists, because it checks the syntax of the sudoers files before saving any changes. If booting into single user mode isn't an option, and nobody has root shells open, you can try to execute /bin/su, but if that allows you to become root without sudo, then you have a massive security flaw. Aside from that, you're out of luck.

Comment: @TimS. It isn't a security flaw if `su` gives access to the root account. It's completely independent from `sudo`. With `su`, you have to type the root password, which of course requires knowing the root password, which of course requires having set a root password.

Comment: Whatever you say. I know the difference between sudo and su, but I digress.

Comment: @TimS. Are you saying that a good entropy root password has no security?

Comment: Never said that, not bothering to argue.

Comment: If you have locked yourself out of root access, then there is no avoiding a reboot.

Answer (score 7):

For this case, there is a line in manual page for `sudoers`:

> The `sudoers` file **should always be edited by the `visudo` command** which locks the file and does grammatical checking.  It is imperative that `sudoers` be free of syntax errors since sudo will not run with a syntactically incorrect `sudoers` file.

It is not in your question, but now there are two possibilities:

1. You have `root` user, you know its password and you can fix `sudo`:

   ```
   su visudo -f /etc/sudoer.d/my_sudoers
   ```
2. You don't have a root password and then you need physical access to the machine to fix things (boot from flash, mount drive, fix file)